# Creating a discretized version of an array

Tags: python, list, numpy, numpy-slicing, discretization

I have a list that describes a profile, such as the next one:

```
dat=[(0, 5),(1, 1),(3,1)]
```

I need to create a discretized version of that profile give a step of time 'dt=0.2'. For instance, the firs column of 'dat' would be:

```
dt = 0.2
time = np.linspace(dat[0][0],dat[-1][0],int(dat[-1][0]/dt)+1)
```

I need to assign the second value of the second column of data, so the new profile would be something like this:

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 5 |
| 0.2 | 5 |
| 0.4 | 5 |
| 0.6 | 5 |
| 0.8 | 5 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 1.2 | 1 |
| 1.4 | 1 |
| 1.6 | 1 |
| 1.8 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2.2 | 1 |
| 2.4 | 1 |
| 2.6 | 1 |
| 2.8 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |

How can I do this?

Comment: Does the second column also need to be discretized?

Comment: @joostblack yes. What I am really discretizing is the first column, but I have to assign a value to the "new discretized" value. So if `dat=[(0, 5),(1, 1),(3,1)]` it means that all values between 1 and 3, will have a value of 1 in the second column as I put in the table

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a better/cleaner/faster way but this is what i have come up with:

```
import numpy as np
dat=[(0, 5),(1, 1),(3,1)]
dt = 0.2

t = [x[0] for x in dat]
col_1 = []
col_2 = []
for idx, (i,j) in enumerate(zip(t[:-1],t[1:])):
    N = int((j-i)/dt)
    col_1 +=np.linspace(i,j,N,endpoint = False).tolist()
    col_2 +=[dat[idx][1]]*N

res = [(i,j) for i,j in zip(col_1, col_2)] + [dat[-1]]
print(res)
```

result:

```
[(0.0, 5), (0.2, 5), (0.4, 5), (0.6000000000000001, 5), (0.8, 5), (1.0, 1), (1.2, 1), (1.4, 1), (1.6, 1), (1.8, 1), (2.0, 1), 
(2.2, 1), (2.4000000000000004, 1), (2.6, 1), (2.8, 1), (3, 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a effor while waiting for a response. Again, I guess it should be a better/cleaner/faster way  to do it.

```
import numpy as np

dat=[(0, 5),(1, 1),(3,1)]
dt=0.2
col_1 = np.arange(dat[0][0],dat[-1][0]+dt,dt)   
col_2 = np.zeros(len(col_1))    
j=0
for i in range(len(dat)):
    while   dat[i][0] <= col_1[j] <= dat[i+1][0]:
       col_2[j] = dat[i][1]
       j += 1
       if j == len(col_1):
           j = 0
```

The result of this is

```
col_1 = array([0. , 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1. , 1.2, 1.4, 1.6, 1.8, 2. , 2.2, 2.4,
       2.6, 2.8, 3. ])
col_2 = array([5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.])
```

Answer (score 0):

You might like to try [`np.repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html):

```
dt = 0.2
dat = np.array([(0, 5),(1, 1),(3,1)])
counts = (np.diff(dat[:,0], axis=0)/dt).astype(int)
counts[0] += 1
sum_counts = ((dat[-1,0] - dat[0,0])/dt).astype(int) + 1
col_1 = np.linspace(dat[0,0], dat[-1,0], sum_counts)
col_2 = np.repeat(dat[:-1,1], counts)
np.transpose([col_1, col_2])
>>> array([[0. , 5. ],
       [0.2, 5. ],
       [0.4, 5. ],
       [0.6, 5. ],
       [0.8, 5. ],
       [1. , 5. ],
       [1.2, 1. ],
       [1.4, 1. ],
       [1.6, 1. ],
       [1.8, 1. ],
       [2. , 1. ],
       [2.2, 1. ],
       [2.4, 1. ],
       [2.6, 1. ],
       [2.8, 1. ],
       [3. , 1. ]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach: you can first create a Series with the desired index from `np.linspace`, then update it with given values, and fill the remaining values with `ffill` and `bfill`:

```
dat_np = np.array(dat, dtype=float)
s = pd.Series(index=np.arange(dat_np[:,0].min(), dat_np[:,0].max() + dt, dt), dtype=float)
s.update(pd.Series(dat_np[:,1], index=dat_np[:,0]))
result = s.ffill()
# this almost works, but we have result[1.0] == 1 instead of result[1.0] == 5;
result.loc[dat_np[:,0]] = np.nan
result = result.ffill().bfill().astype(int)
print(result)
# 0.0    5
# 0.2    5
# 0.4    5
# 0.6    5
# 0.8    5
# 1.0    5
# 1.2    1
# 1.4    1
# 1.6    1
# 1.8    1
# 2.0    1
# 2.2    1
# 2.4    1
# 2.6    1
# 2.8    1
# 3.0    1
# dtype: int64
```

This assumes that all values in the index are exact multiples of `dt`.